Pandas checking if value in column actually checks if value in index?
"490100" in df_exp['ucc'].astype(str).str.strip()
Out[337]: False
(df_exp['ucc'].astype(str) == "490100").any()
Out[339]: True
"490100" in df_exp['ucc'].astype(str).str.strip().values
Out[340]: True

Apparently the check foo in df[column] no longer checks whether foo is a value inside the column, it checks if foo is in the index? This is why explicitely checking against values works?
What is the purpose of this, and how long has  this been operating like this?

the pandas FAQ addresses your question

This question is similar to: How to determine whether a Pandas Column contains a particular value. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your "no longer checks" erroneously suggests that in used to behave like you expected it to behave. It never did. Indeed, it checks if foo is in the index. The "purpose" of that check is self-explanatory. This is similar to how in works with a dict.

This is like this by design:

Using the Python in operator on a Series tests for membership in the index, not membership among the values.

This check is done in the NDFrame class __contains__ method in core/generic.py (_info_axis being the index):
    def __contains__(self, key) -> bool:
        """True if the key is in the info axis"""
        return key in self._info_axis

It's been like this as far as I can remember. The code was already the same in pandas 0.25:
    def __contains__(self, key):
        """True if the key is in the info axis"""
        return key in self._info_axis

